# How to get all intersections between two simple polygons in O(n+k)

Tags: reporting, polygon, intersection

Basically the formulation of the problem I'd like to solve is very simple. Given 2 simple polygons (without self-intersections), report all intersecting edge pairs in *O(n+k)* time, where n - is a total number of edges, k - number of intersections between two polygons.

It is very important to stay within mentioned time hardness. What does surprise me, that I could hardly find any information on this subject. Polygon intersections seems to be such a natural and important problem. Anyway at the moment I don't have a clue if it is even possible to do it in *O(n+k)*.

Can please someone help with the lower bounds for this problem?

Comment: for convex polygons see http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~plante/compGeom/article.html (click on "The Algorithm" for more). For all simple polygons, google "simple polygons" sweep intersection

Comment: Thanks, but of course I'm looking for algorithm for simple polygons. Also sweep algorithm will always likely show _O((n+k)logn)_ complexity - which is not realy suitable in my case.